# Copying tables one database to the other

Tags: sql

This SQL statement runs but then halts:

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [CPI].[dbo].[Transactions] ON
GO

insert into CPI.dbo.Transactions 
(customerid = 24, TransactionId, DepartmentId, ItemId, CategoryId, Quantity, Cost, DateCreated, InvoiceNumber, DataSource, DataSourceId, ImportId, LastUpdate)
select customerid = 104, TransactionId, DepartmentId, ItemId, CategoryId, Quantity, Cost, DateCreated, InvoiceNumber, DataSource, DataSourceId, ImportId, LastUpdate
from Analyzer.dbo.transactions
```

but it processes for about 5 minutes and then this error:

> Msg 547, Level 16, State 0, Line 4 The
>   INSERT statement conflicted with the
>   FOREIGN KEY constraint
>   "FK_Transactions_Customers". The
>   conflict occurred in database "CPI",
>   table "dbo.Customers", column
>   'CustomerId'. The statement has been
>   terminated.

Comment: If you post code or XML, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code" button (101 010) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The message is pretty clear: you're trying to insert a value into the `Transactions` table that has a `CustomerId` referencing the table `dbo.Customers` (on the column `CustomerId`) that doesn't exist in the customers table.

Obviously, there is a foreign key relationship between `Transactions` and `Customers` and your INSERT statement is violation that referential integrity.

Most likely, you a) haven't synchronized your `Customers` table between the two servers (yet), or b) you missed some entries somehow.